# How to change the default value of a data grid view combo box column with selected value from itself

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

i have a data grid view combo box column in my data grid view. On on load event of form i am loading the companies name in combo box column and through cell formatting event i am giving the default value to data grid view combo box column.

Now if i select different value from combo box column it does not get reflected. means only default value is there.

My code for on load and cell formatting is

```
   public void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
        c.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\Accounts\\Accounts\\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        c.Open();

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && Viewcashvoucher.mk != "")
        {
            string mky = Viewcashvoucher.mk;
                 string q = "select * from lgr where main_key ='" + mky + "'";
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, c);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            e.Value = dr["account_n"].ToString();

        }
        }
        c.Close();
    }
```

and on load event is

```
private void Cash_Voucher_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mky = Viewcashvoucher.mk;
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
        c.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\Accounts\\Accounts\\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        c.Open();


            string q = "select max(date) from lgr ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, c);
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                if (rd.Read())
                {
                    DateTime date = rd.GetDateTime(0);
                    if (date != null)
                    {
                        tbdate.Text = date.ToShortDateString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tbdate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            }
            c.Close();
            c.Open();
            string q1 = "select account_n from master";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(q1, c);
            SqlDataReader rd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn acname = dataGridView1.Columns[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            while (rd1.Read())
            {
                acname.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(rd1["account_n"]));


            }
```

}

actually i am using same data grid view for insert and update operation.  i want that as user select different value from combo box list the default value should be replaced by selected one.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also bind the **DataBindingComplete** event.  The only difference in previous and this answer is @Junaith bind the **RowAdded** event mean it will call the function every time you add the row.  and here in mycase I bound **DataBindingComplete** event which will fire after the grid is full loaded mean this will call only once and that time it will check the all the checkbox in first column of the grid for all the lines.

```
mygrid.DataBindingComplete +=
       new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(mygrid_DataBindingComplete);
```

then and you have to define a function name as **mygrid_DataBindingComplete**

```
    private void mygrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView temp = (DataGridView)sender;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in temp.Rows)
        {
            // here 0 indicating the checbox column is the first column in grid
            // first column so index would be 0.  true will check the checkbox
            rw.Cells[0].Value = true;
        }
     }
```

Comment: i have no check boxes in data grid view. actually i want to load same data grid view for insert and update.Insert part is over and working.

Comment: so you mean you want to set the value in combo grid filling and then they if u save the record this select value in combo doesn't reflect. is it so?

Comment: i hv another form on which i have selected all the records i a data grid view. On dgvcellcontentclick event i m calling same form which is previously used for insrtn and through dgvcell formatting event i am settiing the default value of columns to the same on which content i have clicked. Problem is here that there are multiple rows i want to fetch in dgv. and i am not able to edit the columns(textbox).in dgvcomboboxcolumn in which i have loaded some names by on load event, if i change the default value of combo box column with another value by selecting from the list, it not get reflected

Comment: see if you are saying on button click if does not reflect the changed value i am not getting .. I tried with an example.  In datagridview i just inserted a combobox column and on data binding i changed the value on particular condition and then on form load i changed the dropdown value and select the row and click the button to get the whole row value and i am getting the correct value ..

Pls refer the following sample 
[Download Sample](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2TVdVZUJhR0M3eUU)

Comment: sir will u please send me your yahoo id.. i will send you my project @Deepak

Comment: any other id than g mail.???? coz gmail not accept exe and other type files... i tried but failure notice came into my inbox. so  please send me another id or tell me another way to share my project with u.@ deepak

Comment: i have mailed you.. check the issue.

Comment: thank you @deepak  for your valuable time. I have checked your mail i know that there are 3 rows get affected against a a single main_key. and this is what exactly i want to do. there could be more than 90 rows agsinst one main_key. i want to load them all.

Comment: mean when i click on first form you want to load all 3 records for that main_key ?? is that so?? seems little awkward, but ok if its ur requirement.. so its done ur still any issue.?

Comment: i am not even able to load all the records if i use for loop it showing me index out of range. and in evn single record i am not able to change the default value. any solution?? or which are the possible events on to which i can try?? @deepak

Comment: hey i will send u the solution i mean u want to load all the three record  right??? i will try and will seend u the code but my lappi doesnt have sql server so that i cannt test it.. i will send u on mndy .

Comment: hi i checkd ur code.. but its really confusing code.. i dnt know why u r getting and filling the records in grid on formatting cell event .. it will create a while loop if u try to add more then one record.. and when u are trying to get the all the records for the main_key and want to display all in grid then which date and voucher number you will set in text field.? its really damn confusing..

Comment: let me explain. i want to add vouchers in which number of entries can be added but their voucher number will be the same so does main_key. now i want to update any voucher say 5001 and i want to edit entry number 20. so how can i do it??? is it any another way to load all the records and in data grid view combo box i want that all the accounts name should be added. is it possible ?? @ deepak

Comment: you want like [Check Image](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2WUNhWVk2MkQ0akk) this image?? 

I have mailed you the code check it out..

Comment: thnx @ deepak. evn i hve done it before in same way. thank you very much for your time and response.

Comment: yup @deepak its working according to req. thanxx a ton

Answer (score 0):

`CellFormatting` event handler is not the right place to set the default value. CellFormatting occurs whenever the content of the cells needs to be formated for display. Whenever you the change the value in the combobox and accept the value, this event is raised and the default value code resets the user selection.

In `DataGridView.RowsAdded` you could set the defalut value for the combobox cell for the newly added row(s)

Sample Code:

```
void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < (e.RowIndex+e.RowCount); i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[comboboxcolumn_index].Value = defaultvalue;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: @ Junaith . it is not working. i have added items in data grid view combo box column on ON load event. i want that as i select the item from comobobox, the selected item should replace the default one

Comment: whnever a new row is added, data grid view combo box column replace the selected item with default one

Comment: Try moving the default value code into the OnLoad event handler after you populate the combo box column..

Comment: even i was thinking about it ;). will ask you if i face some problem. @Junaith

Answer (score 0):

hai you can Just use this on RowAdded Event or DataGridview comboboxcolumn creation time. It will Set the Default Value

```
comboboxcolumn_Name.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Please Select";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < (e.RowIndex+e.RowCount); i++)
    {
        comboboxcolumn_Name.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Please Select";
    }
}
```